# How can I whitelist characters from a string in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, strip

My question is quite simple, I am trying to strip any character that is not A-Z, or 0-9 from a string.

Basically this is the process I am trying to do:

```
whitelist=['a',...'z', '0',...'9']

name = '_abcd!?123'

name.strip(whitelist)

print(name)

>>> abcd123
```

What's important to know is that I can't just only print valid characters in name. I need to actually use the variable in its changed state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` and provide a pattern that exactly matches what you are trying to remove:

```
import re
result = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', '_abcd!?123')
```

Output:

```
'abcd123'
```

Comment: fyi, the `[^   ]` syntax is a negated range in regex.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) with a list comprehension

```
import string
whitelist = set(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits)
name = ''.join(c for c in name if c in whitelist)
```

Comment: better approach if u do not want to use `re` or `regex`

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple regex:

```
new_string = re.sub('[chars to remove]', '', old_string)
```

Please also note that strings are immutable. You need to assign a new variable in order to change one.